# url_field to accept non http:// or https:// links

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried useing `url_field` tag in my form.

I should be able to enter non `http://` urls, e.g I would need to enter `www.google.com`. But rails url_field does not allow this.

Is there any way to do it?

This is my current setup:

```
<%= f.url_field :english_link,  :class => "form-control", :placeholder =>"Type your message", :rows => "4", maxlength: 130, spellcheck: true %>
```

I also tried using a regex within `f.text_field` , but it is not working.

```
<%= f.text_field :english_link, pattern: /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Enter URL Link Here" %>
```

I checked to see if the regex works in rubular.com, and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern would be evaluated on the browser side. Nice solution but it wont work everywhere (depends on the browser). Not sure if regex is exactly same syntax as Ruby perhaps you should cross reference taht. Check in your HTML output if the regex follows the requred syntax (perhaps you should replace // with "")

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your model for example `Posts.rb` lets say it contains the field `english_link`

So in your model `Post.rb` you can do a check like this:

```
validates_format_of : english_link, :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
```